# Flask-Admin: Export CSV

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I am trying to export a ModelView's data to CSV. Activating `can_export = True` as recommended in the docs does nothing.
I inspected my Flask-Admin installation, and even though it was the latest version (1.3.0), the source is different, so I downloaded and installed the `master.zip` available on GitHub.

Now, the Export button appears on my View, but clicking it generates `BuildError: ('tableview.export_csv', {}, None)`

I tried manually pasting the source's `export_csv` method into my class (which seems kludgy), but all I get is an empty CSV file.

How can I let the user download a CSV with the table view data?

My code for reference:

```
class DataTable(Secure):
    def __init__(self, modelclass, session, **kwargs):
        super(DataTable, self).__init__(modelclass, session, **kwargs)
        self.can_export = True
        self.column_filters = [c[0] for c in self._list_columns]
# Add view to menu
admin.add_view(DataTable(modelclass, name='TESTE', category=u'TEST'))
```

Comment: That error is typical if you are not passing in all the required arguments. Can you post your method definition, and the code that invokes it?

Comment: My guess is that you have two versions of Flask-Admin when you replaced it with `master.zip`. Try a clean install from the zip file?

Comment: @JasonHeine I added the code for reference.

Comment: @Rafael can you post your export_csv method, as well as the form, or link that calls it. Are you using url_for('export_csv')?

Comment: @nathancahill I uninstalled the current version and reinstalled from setup.py. Same results. Is it possible that `master.zip` does not have the same content as the web version of GitHub?

Comment: @JasonHeine I don't have a custom export_csv method. This method should be inherited from BaseView class, but for some reason, my Flask-Admin installation doesn't have this code.
Tomorrow I will have to resort to copy and paste each file from the web version, as it appears that GitHub's `master.zip` does not have the same content as the source shown on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

1. There were multiple versions of Flask-Admin installed: All of these were 1.3.0, but Flask-Admin's code on GitHub changed without changing the version number. I manually deleted offending folder my environment's site-packages.
2. Flask-Admin's master.zip on GitHub does not contain the exact code as the website. This is not obvious, and I only found out because I needed a feature that was listed in the Documentation, but did not actually exist on master.zip, only on the Web version.